# Concatenate multiple rows where I have information from a substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012

I have a txt file with more than 500MB of information and the only information that creates a pattern is the substring using each line, taking position 10 and incrementing 7 positions. I would like to know a way to group these equal values using sql server.

My TXT.

0000009500**0005869**1 + more info

0000009500**0005869**2 + more info.

A record can hava more than two lines.  I have to get the information in bold.

My code to import in sql server

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([Coluna 0],10,7) as Matricula,
    [Coluna 0]
 FROM [POC].[dbo].[fita_espelho_s49000] as tabela_inicial
```

And my code to concatenate my datas with the number in bold like primary key.

```
SELECT  
    Matricula,
    STUFF((
        SELECT '' + B.[Coluna 0] 
        FROM dbo.tabela_v1 B 
        WHERE ISNULL(B.Matricula, '') = ISNULL(A.Matricula, '')
        ORDER BY B.[Coluna 0] 
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''
    ) AS Concatenado
FROM
    dbo.tabela_v1 A
GROUP BY 
    Matricula
ORDER BY 
    Matricula
```

Comment: edit the question add some sample data & desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Re-arranging several rows into a single row using `for xml path`.

I suggest using a cross apply to establish the `matricula` column (from a substring) this allows us to use that column alias in the select clause. Then, a second cross apply is used to build the concatenation across rows using `for xml path`. I added row identifiers in that concatenation which is optional, but makes this answer a little easier to read I hope. Finally the row number generated in the initial subquery is used to filter out only the rows we need (& to avoid using distinct across a very wide column).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/455f5/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE fita_espelho_s49000
    ([Coluna_0] varchar(36))
;

INSERT INTO fita_espelho_s49000
    ([Coluna_0])
VALUES
    ('000000950000058691 + more info'),
    ('000000950000058692 + even more info.')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
with CTE as (
      select
             matricula
           , coluna_0
           , row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as rn
      from fita_espelho_s49000
      cross apply (
         SELECT SUBSTRING([Coluna_0],10,7) as Matricula
        ) ca1
  )
select
       matricula
     , ca1.all_coluna
from CTE t
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
             STUFF(
                   (SELECT
                          ',ROW' + cast(rn as varchar) +',' + [Coluna_0]
                    FROM CTE x
                    WHERE t.matricula = x.matricula
                    FOR XML PATH ('')
                    )
             , 1, 1, '')
         ) ca1 (all_coluna)
where rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/455f5/1/0)**:

```
| matricula |                                                                    all_coluna |
|-----------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   0000586 | ROW1,000000950000058691 + more info,ROW2,000000950000058692 + even more info. |
```